# OpenCv 2.4.7 on iOS error background_segm.hpp #include <list> not found

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, opencv, ios7

Well I've been trying to figure this out for about an hour now and tried all the solutions I could find all over the web and they all failed.

It must be a common error but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using opencv 2.4.8 on iOS platform and I am doing some human detection with their trained svm. All my code is happy, however i cannot build due to the error:

```
background_segm.hpp file list not found
```

ALso just to be clear I have tried to change all my files to .mm and that didn't work either.
You can find the project on github: https://github.com/mbaptist23/open-fusion-iOS

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry I butchered the title here. I am using opencv 2.4.8 the freshest stable build. sorry about that

Comment: hey one solution to this is to use cocoapods to resolve the dependencies for you not only for opencv but for any objc frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when  using opencv 2.4.9, compiling for Mac. In my case, this error was caused by including the opencv header files in a *.c file rather than in a .cpp file. See [this discussion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=991552#c12) for more information.